# jquery datatable binding data property to content that is displayed

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I have my jQuery datatable plugin installed and I've initialized it like this:

```
   $('#datatable-responsive2').DataTable({
            //    data: data,
               // deferRender: true,
                "pageLength": 25,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "filter": false,
                "orderMulti": false,

                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Administrator/LoadData/",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype":"json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "FirstName", "name": "Lela", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Email", "name": "Email", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Active", "name": "Status", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "targets": -1, "data": "UserId", "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "FirstName", "name": "Full name", "autoWidth": true }

                ]
            });
```

Please note this column:

```
  { "targets": -1, "data": "UserId", "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>", "autoWidth": true }
```

I've followed their documentation on how to render an HTML element there... But what I need now and wasn't able to figure how do I actually set a certain attribute for this HTML element inside the datatable when its being generated...

As u can see I've set data source for the datatable as UserId, and now I'd like each button "Click" to have value whatever the value of UserId is...

Can someone help me out?

P.S. so I want to output an HTML element in that column whos structure would be something like this:

```
<button values="whatever the value of userId is..?">Click me event</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define the [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) property of the column for that which would be the following :

```
{ 
    "targets": -1, 
    "data": "UserId", 
    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                return "<button id='"+ data +"'>Click!</button>";
                            }, 
    "autoWidth": true 
}
```

The `data` property will be containing `UserId` in it which can be used in the `render` function.

You can refer to the [**documentation**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) of it [**here**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

Comment: Ehsan, this is probably the most useful reply that I got lately. Very straightforward and neat :) Happy coding!

Comment: glad that it helped you :)